# How can I undo compilation of a file overwriting another file?

Tags: c++, g++

I was trying to compile my c++ program using the command `g++ program.cpp -o program` in order to create an executable with the same name as the actual program but used `g++ program.cpp -o program.cpp` and now my code looks like gibberish. Is there anyway to reverse it?

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Oof. `-o` specifies where you want the compiled binary to be placed. It can not be reversed. You can try to find programs to decompile it, but it is likely more trouble than it is worth and wont produce a perfect result.

Comment: Since you've asked here, I presume you had decided not to use version control software like **git** or **mercurial** to keep track of your changes and act as a recoverable backup in case of catastrophe.

Comment: You clearly can't use your source file as the same name as the binary. A .cpp file is a text source code file. You just wiped it out completely - you totally overwrote it with the output. You're simply out of luck - you'll have to start writing your code again from scratch. It doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Unless you have backups (and have actually backed up your source file) there is no way to recover it. If you're using a version control system, you can revert to an older version of your source file. But, since you are manually typing in commands to compile your file (otherwise you probably couldn't have typed a command like `g++ program.cpp -o program.cpp` to overwrite your source file) then it is likely you are not using a version control system or backup software. So your source file is lost.  Try doing homework to understand what command lines do BEFORE you enter/commit them, not after.

Comment: Too bad you are using clang. This typo is quite common, don't feel too bad, you are far from the first, it is so common that some compilers like gcc actively check for it... Unless you have some backup (some editors automatically keep some backup temporarily), there is nothing you can do now.

Comment: @Peter I know what the command line does, it was just a typo that I did not mean to write, I was typing fast and I entered that by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing this process is semi-possible, but I do not recommend it. It is easier to just rewrite the program, as the compilation loses a ton of info. If you had compiled it with `-g` I believe it would be possible to recover the source (I have no idea though how one would do that).
If you have to reverse it you need to use a decompiler such as Cutter/Ghidra, but the result will need to be cleaned up. Example:

```cpp
#inlcude <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string a = "Hey";
    a += '\n';
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `g++ test.cc -o test`, and then decompiling with Ghidra, gets us:

```c
undefined8 main(void){
  long in_FS_OFFSET;
  allocator<char> local_49;
  basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> local_48 [40];
  long local_20;
  
  local_20 = *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28);
  std::allocator<char>::allocator();
                    /* try { // try from 001012a3 to 001012a7 has its CatchHandler @ 001012fc */
  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string
            ((char *)local_48,(allocator *)&DAT_00102005);
  std::allocator<char>::~allocator(&local_49);
                    /* try { // try from 001012c2 to 001012d9 has its CatchHandler @ 0010131a */
  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::operator+=
            (local_48,"\n");
  std::operator<<((basic_ostream *)std::cout,(basic_string *)local_48);
  std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::~basic_string
            (local_48);
  if (local_20 != *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28)) {
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
    __stack_chk_fail();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Pretty far gone, huh. The original program was only a few lines, but this seems a monstrosity. By knowing what to look for you can ignore things the compiler placed there to be safe like `__stack_chk_fail()`, and the anything that has `in_FS_OFFSET` or `local_20` in it. But it is extremely laboursome in general. With some code it might be easier, but parts of it might be optimised away etc. so it is generally not recommended.

Note: I did not paste it here but at `DAT_00102005`, the string `"Hey"` is contained.